# How to capture sets of repeating characters using regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
line = "..12345678910111213141516171820212223"
regex = re.compile(r'((?:[a-zA-Z0-9])\1+)')
print ("not coming here")
matches = re.findall(regex,line)
print (matches)
```

In the above code i am trying to capture the groups of repeating characters.

So for example i need the answers like :
111
222
etc.

But when i run the above code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "First.py", line 3, in <module>
    regex = re.compile(r'((?:[a-zA-Z0-9])\1+)')
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\re.py", lin
e 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\re.py", lin
e 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_compile
.py", line 536, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 829, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 778, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 524, in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)
  File "C:\Users\bhatsubh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\sre_parse.p
y", line 415, in _escape
    len(escape))
sre_constants.error: cannot refer to an open group at position 16
```

Someone please guide me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (probably) want

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Wj3NKf/2/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
line = "..12345678910111213141516171820212223"
regex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+')

matches = [match.group(0) for match in regex.finditer(line)]
print (matches)
# ['111', '222']
```

Comment: Yes, but that does not work with findall - it just prints the first char in the repeating group.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: True, that's why I added some code as well (using a list comprehension, that is).

Answer (score 2):

A group reference cannot be found inside another group. If all you want to do is print those repeating chars out, there's a small hack you can use, with `re.sub`:

```
def foo(m):
     print(m.group(0))
     return ''

_ = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+', foo, line) # use [a-zA-Z0-9] if you don't want to match underscores
111
222
```

Comment: Not bad either :)

Comment: @Jan Thank you! Yours is less hacky though, I like it more than this.

Comment: OP is the one to decide, I'd reckon.

Comment: `[\w\d]` = `\w`. Besides, `\w` also matches `_`, so it is different from what OP uses. Also, since OP uses Python 3.5, `\w` matches all Unicode letters and digits by default (thus, `re.A` modifier might be required if OP needs to only handle ASCII).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, I kinda realised that, but left this in, because of its conciseness. Still, added a note because that should be the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Quite possible it is also working for OP, sure, why not.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible* to do this with `.findall`, but it's simpler to do it with `.finditer`, as shown in Jan's answer.

```
import re

line = "..12345678910111213141516171820212223"
regex = re.compile(r'(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2+)')

matches = [t[0] for t in regex.findall(line)]
print(matches)
```

**output**

```
['111', '222']
```

We use `\2`, because `\1` refers to the pattern in the outer parentheses and `\2`  refers to the pattern in the inner parentheses.